# Entity Framework and stored procedures with optional parameters

Tags: sql, entity-framework, stored-procedures, optional-parameters

Is there any way to have the `Map Entity to Functions` section ignore an optional parameter?

I have a `set_X` stored procedure, if I save a copy as `insert_X` (and remove the `ID` parameter then it works fine. otherwise I get the error (I think because it's mapping the ID on both the IN and OUT of the procedure(?)):

> Unable to determine a valid ordering for dependent operations.
>   Dependencies may exist due to foreign key constraints, model
>   requirements, or store-generated values.

So is there any way I can just tell it to ignore this property without adding in a new dummy property in my Model Entity?

Edit:

I have worked out that if I add a new property such as `NewID` then I can map this to the `@ID` parameter of my stored procedure without.. but this causes me to have an additional property in my Model Entity. Is there any way I can map a stored procedure parameter in EF to a fixed value instead (such as `NULL` or `0`) without having to add a new property to my Entity.

Comment: Not as far as I am aware. Drives me nuts every time... I create insert and update procs that call eg, the set proc.